# pinging multiple IP's using Bash returns a missing ']' error

Tags: bash

I'm currently attempting to write a script to help ping a text list of hosts to see whether or not the specified node is running.  I'm using Git for Windows v2.17.0.  The code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Program name: pingall2.sh

date
cat     C:/Users/mooe001/Documents/list.txt | while read output
do
    ping -c 1 "$output" > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "node $output is up"
    else
        echo "node $output is down"
    fi
done
```

It currently returns a `line 8 [: missing ']'` error but I'm positive the space after the 0 should resolve this.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Rewrote the script (same as above) and no longer returns the error.  Still not quite sure what the cause might have been.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Looks like you are using WSL. Did you write the list in windows ?

Comment: Are you using WSL? If you wrote the list in Windows, check for the correct line endings! You actually don’t need `test` (aka `[`), just do `if ping -c1 "$output" >/dev/null; then` instead.

Comment: While answering the other questions, will you add an example from your list to the question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify, *do not* use comments. :)

Comment: Maybe you could simply use `nmap -sP -iL C:/Users/mooe001/Documents/list.txt` instead

Comment: Try:
    bash -x pingall.sh  -- this runs bash with some trace lines.